# DataGridView creates extra lines when I import a text file into it.

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to import a .txt file to a DataGrid. The problem is although the code works mostly OK, when import the .txt file, it creates to extra lines, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnOl5.jpg);

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Cabbaa\Desktop";
        DialogResult a = ofd.ShowDialog();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
        if (lines.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var columnName in lines.FirstOrDefault()
                .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Time, Class);
            }
            foreach (var cellValues in lines)
            {
                var cellArray = cellValues
                    .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean the empty row at the bottom? (i think that is the "add-a-new-record row" of the datagrid. you can turn that off by setting `dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false`)

Comment: Oh no, the first two ones. I think you can see them if you check the imgur file I linked.

Comment: Ah! i see 'em. hang on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the first foreach loop of your code.

```
        //you are adding rows to the column here, you are not adding headers 
        foreach (
          var columnName in 
          lines.FirstOrDefault().Split(new[] {','}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        )
        {
            //since we split the line on commas, 
            //we are adding a row to the table for every 
            //CSV value we found in the current line. 
            //this is causing the "garbage" rows you are seeing
            //i do not know where "Time" and "Class" come from here. 
            //they weren't part of that first line in this example. 
            //my guess is you do not need this loop at all.
            //since the headers already neatly show up on the table in your screenshot.
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Time, Class);
        }

        //this works just fine.
        foreach (var cellValues in lines)
        {
            var cellArray = cellValues
                .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
        }
```

Comment: I tried that. Corrupted first two lines remain. But this time, it skipped my first line of 3 lines. When I set the skip value to 0, then displayed all 3 of my entries yet still the first two remained.

Comment: I figured out why that happened and updated the answer.

Comment: The funny thing is, the first two lines weren't technically "corrupted". the only reason that first loop compiled is because `Time` and `Class` resolved to existing class definitions or instances. the value in the datagrid cells was the namespace and class name of these definitions.